# Make permanent changes to config files for Laravel 5 via GUI script

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using `Laravel 5` and building an app that will need to be able to add /edit additional filesystem settings via the application itself, instead of doing so manually. I want to be able to add new config settings via a GUI instead of manually.

I found reference to : [this Link](https://github.com/daftspunk/laravel-config-writer) but it appears to have some issues with Laravel 5.

Is there another / better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your code write to php files doesn't feel right to me. Whenever something can be changed by the user, I would store it in your database. It shouldn't be that hard I think.

You could create an Eloquent model like `FileSystemConfig` with the required columns to store your filesystem specific config values. Something like `[disk, key, value]`. Your GUI would just interact with that model to Create / Read / Update / Delete disks.

To have these 'dynamic' config values be picked up by the application, all you need to do is register them in your ConfigServiceProvider (that should already be present in your App/Providers). That would probably look something like this (untested!)

```
class ConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {

        $fileConfig = FileSystemConfig::all()
            ->groupBy('disk')
            ->transform(function($group) {
                $out = [];
                foreach ($group as $item) {
                    $out[$item['key']] = $item['value'];
                }
                return $out;
            })
        ;
        config([
            'filesystems.disks' => $fileConfig
        ]);
    }
}
```